# Too many connections to mongodb ReplicaSet?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am writing a Python app to work with Mongodb on the backend with pymongo.

I have created a model classes to mirror documents inserted on the database
this is a quick example of models in action:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    class MyApp(App):

        db_client = MongoClient(replicaset='erpRS').test

        def build(self):
            model = models.UserModel(name='NewUser', cpf='01234567890')
            print(model)
            model.save()
            model_from_db = models.UserModel.objects.find_one()
            print(model_from_db)

        def on_stop(self):
            self.db_client.close()
```

My model classes (ex: UserModel) create an instance of Collection as a class property to be used  for CRUD operations. So on the snippet above, I create a user and save it to the db. then I fetch a previously saved user from the db. When app stops, `on_stop()` is called and pymongo client is and its connections are closed.

This code is working as it is intended.

But monitoring the database I can see that just this snipped above, with a single model instance, and thusly, a single Collection instance, and two calls to CRUD operations, open as much as 6 connections to the database.

On further inspection mongodb iself seems to keep a number of connections open. After a single run of this program, my 3 node ReplicaSet, all running on the same machine, has 19 connections open.

Is this a reasonable behavior? Are there supposed to be this many open connections?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB has connection pool. You shouldn't worry too much about having 19 connections open. The cost of one connection is 1mb file on the node.

What you should think about is refactoring your code and use DI to pass around MongoClient object.

Creating a new MongoClient and a connection every time you instantiate a class is way too expensive.

Comment: Only one MongoClient and Collection object (per collection on the db) is ever instantiated, which is why I thought this many connections was weird. I realize this is  far below the connections limit, but it seems like a large number for the case I described

Comment: The close() method doesn't immediately close connections. Instead, it marks them for closure, and they are only closed once they're returned to the connection pool. Therefore, when there's a high frequency of opening and closing a single connection, some time is required to close those marked for closure. As a result, you might observe multiple open connections, such as 19, instead of just one